# want to paste colums A & b from one wkbook into another wkbook under specific header (name of requstee)

Tags: excel, vba

```
Dim MyColumn  As String, lastrow As Long, wb As Workbook, cell As Range, rngAddress As Range, wbTarget As Workbook
Set clipboard = New MSForms.FataObject
Set wb = Workbooks("Holiday form (11) .xlsm")
With wb.Sheets("sheet4").Select
lastrow = Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
Range("A2:B2" & lastrow).Copy
End With
Set wbTarget = Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\msheppar\Desktop\new holiday project\working forms" & "\Master Holiday Tracker.xlsm")
Set rngAddress = wbTarget.Sheets("sheet1").Range("A1:BZ1").Find("name")
```

If rngAddress Is Nothing Then
       Exit Sub
  End If
  Range(rngAddress, rngAddress.End(xlDown)).Paste
End Sub

Comment: Dim MyColumn  As String
    Dim lastrow As Long
    Dim wb As Workbook
    Dim cell As Range
    Dim rngAddress As Range
    Dim wbTarget As Workbook

    Set clipboard = New MSForms.FataObject
    Set wb = Workbooks("Holiday form (11) .xlsm")
    With wb.Sheets("sheet4").Select
    lastrow = Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    Range("A2:B2" & lastrow).Copy
    End With

Comment: Set wbTarget = Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\msheppar\Desktop\new holiday project\working forms" & "\Master Holiday Tracker.xlsm")
    Set rngAddress = wbTarget.Sheets("sheet1").Range("A1:BZ1").Find("name")
  If rngAddress Is Nothing Then
       Exit Sub
  End If
  Range(rngAddress, rngAddress.End(xlDown)).Paste
End Sub

Comment: Apologies, had to submit it in two pieces. what am i doing wrong,that it all appears as one block?